# Read and write an ArrayList of ArrayLists containing Parcelable Objects to pass in an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

I just changed all serializable classes in my project to parcelable classes.
Everything is working fine, except for that one class which is made of an ArrayList containing another ArrayList. I already debugged.
There is no error when writing this ArrayList. But I get an error while reading it.

This is the class where the error happens:

```
public class Timetable implements Parcelable
{
private int actLap = 0;
private ArrayList<Lap> timetable;
private ArrayList<Location> loggedLocations;
private Date startTime; ...
...
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    out.writeInt(actLap);
    out.writeTypedList(timetable); //no error here
    out.writeTypedList(loggedLocations); ...
...
    private Timetable(Parcel in)
{
    actLap          = in.readInt();
    in.readTypedList(timetable, Lap.CREATOR); //error after this line
    in.readTypedList(loggedLocations, Location.CREATOR);
    startTime       = (Date)in.readSerializable();
    bestLap         = in.readParcelable(Lap.class.getClassLoader());
    track           = in.readParcelable(Track.class.getClassLoader());
    description     = in.readString();
}
```

Here are the other classes:

```
public class Lap implements Parcelable
{   
private ArrayList<Time> sectorTimes = new ArrayList<Time>();
private Time laptime; ...
...
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    out.writeTypedList(sectorTimes);
    out.writeParcelable(laptime,flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Lap> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Lap>()
{
    public Lap createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Lap(in);
    }

    public Lap[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Lap[size];
    }
};

private Lap(Parcel in)
{
    in.readTypedList(sectorTimes, Time.CREATOR);
    laptime     = in.readParcelable(Time.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

And this class:

```
public class Time implements Parcelable
{
private long timeLong;
private String timeString;...
...
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    out.writeLong(timeLong);
    out.writeString(timeString);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Time> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Time>()
{
    public Time createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Time(in);
    }

    public Time[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Time[size];
    }
};

private Time(Parcel in)
{
    timeLong = in.readLong();
    timeString = in.readString();
}
```

Like I already said, everything works fine (there are more Parcelable classes which I pass with intents (including a single ArrayList) and which I save in files).
So can you guys help me to write and read that double ArrayList?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code is as posted, then you're just missing the initialization of the ArrayLists, i.e.

```
private Timetable(Parcel in)
{
    // readTypeList() needs an existing List<> to load.
    timetable = new ArrayList<Lap>();
    loggedLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    actLap          = in.readInt();
    in.readTypedList(timetable, Lap.CREATOR);
    in.readTypedList(loggedLocations, Location.CREATOR);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. I had in mind that this method would create a new Arraylist.